# What is tilde ~ meaning in coding Mathematica?

Tags: scripting

I got this code to solve problem 500 in euler project. I was managing to figure out what they mean but got stuck in translating the tilde (~). It seems tilde has no specific meaning and when I change the code to Tilde[Times[#1, #2],Mod,500500507]&, which should be an equivalent definition, it does not work. Could anyone give a hint? Thanks.

```
Fold[Times[#1, #2]~Mod~500500507 &, 1, (Sort@
Flatten@(NestWhileList[#^2 &, Prime@#, # < 10^7 &] & /@ 
   Range@PrimePi@(10^7)))[[1 ;; 500500]]]
```

Comment: see [Infix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html)

Comment: See here specifically: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thank you all soooooo much for your help! I will never get to know them without you.

Comment: In Mathematica, highlight the tilde (or other unknown symbols) and press `F1` for help.